# Can we use meta to share announcements regarding special schools and camps?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

First of all let me commit the crime and then plead innocence.

I recently found out that the [**3rd Quantum Gravity and Quantum Geometry (QGQG3) School**](http://www.fuw.edu.pl/~kostecki/school3/index.html) is being held in **Zakopane, Poland** from **Feb 28 - March 11, 2011**. The list of speakers is wide-ranging and impressive. I especially encourage all my string theory friends on this site to attend so that you can hear the story from the horse's mouth, so to speak ;)

Given that we have a lively and growing community which has the potential to seed highly productive inter-disciplinary collaborations, it seems that there should be a bulletin board where we can share such announcements. This sort of arrangement could, along with the recent suggestion of a physics journal club, be one of the *adjunct* social functions this site could easily provide. Or maybe not so easily. It is easy to offer suggestions when you are not the one who has to dig into the entrails of the site's code to make changes :>/ In the absence of any specialized tools we could, **by common consent**, make use of meta for such announcements.

How does the community feel about this possibility?

Comment: I like that the conference is in Poland but I don't think I'll have time to attend. Thanks for letting us know anyway though. It's definitely useful to have announcements like this around.

Answer (score 3):

There are already few questions asking for e.g. PhD or postdoc positions. I don't see any reason why not creating also a CW big-list of winter/summer schools and conferences. Only thing to decide is how specific that question should be. Perhaps we should create one question for each topic (like quantum gravity) separately. Also, this doesn't belong to meta, it's perfectly relevant on the main site as a soft-question.

Answer (score 0):

The chat room sort of functions as a bulletin board when we use it infrequently. That might not be a bad place to post announcements about these sorts of things. It could be done in addition to announcing them on the main site (or meta) if we decide that that's okay.

I highly doubt that the SE team will change their software to add a specialized feature for this.

Comment: The physics chat room is, to put it mildly, desolate. Without more activity on chat it serves no purposes to put any notices there.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Marek that this would be on topic at the main site, although I'm not sure how to put this into the SE engine. Maybe we<sup>+</sup> should start a dedicated blog?

<sub><sup>+</sup> I must admit by "we" I mean "someone else" since I wouldn't have the time to manage it...</sub>

Comment: Actually with content management systems and instant wikis its pretty easy to set one up. The only thing needed is web hosting. The "free" options - for hosting a blog - always fall too short. So if someone would be willing to shell out a few dollars a month .......

Comment: I already have a couple of web servers which I use for my own sites, so I could definitely take care of setting up a blog. I'd just want to know that people were committed to the idea before taking the plunge and setting it up. (Alternatively, we'd probably want to talk to the Stack Exchange team first and ask if they can offer anything in that vein, since they certainly know web hosting)

Comment: @David I'm sure you will find no shortage of interested volunteers on this site ... Question is how to single them out for the purpose of commitment to such an enterprise. I'm sure a solution will present itself in due time.